# Jenkins - Change property if job is started by upstream job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have 2 jobs in Jenkins: Parent and Child (a successful build on Parent triggers a build on Child).

There is a property VALUE in both projects:

- Project Parent: VALUE=FIRST
- Project Child: VALUE=NEXT

What I want is if I build the job Child directly, VALUE=NEXT. But if the job Child is started by the upstream job Parent, the property is overwritten and VALUE=FIRST.

I tried setting a post-build action on Parent to trigger a parameterized build on Child and defined the parameter VALUE=FIRST. However after running Parent and triggering a build on Child, I looked at the console output for Child and VALUE=NEXT: it did not change.

(I tested passing the parameter VALUE to Child if VALUE is undefined in Child and it worked, VALUE equaled FIRST. So Jenkins is able to pass the parameter but it's not able to overwrite the parameter if it's already defined in the downstream job.)

How do I overwrite the property in the downstream job?

Comment: Where do you define the "VALUE" property in both projects ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I resolved the issue.

VALUE was defined in the Child jobs as an environment variable via EnvInject, not as a parameter. So when trying to pass the parameter VALUE to overwrite the environment variable VALUE, it was running into issues.

By modifying the Child jobs to make VALUE a parameter, I was able to successfully pass the new parameter from the Parent job to the Child job.

Comment: So how it was defined in both projects ended up being the issue

Answer (score 2):

Please note that this requires some approvals if you run your scripts in sandbox.

```
isUpstreamTriggered = (currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause) != null)
```

For more information [the example I've based on](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/pipeline-examples/get-build-cause/getBuildCause.groovy) and [the actual Cause class](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Cause.java).

Answer (score 2):

This is old post , but I think its worth giving second option to find if current build is caused by upstream project.

```
   `def upstreamProjectCount = 0;
    currentBuild.upstreamBuilds?.each { b ->
        upstreamProjectCount++
    }
    if (upstreamProjectCount == 0) {
        echo "Not a upstream project"
    } else {
        echo "upstream project"
    }
```

Comment: Cheers, this works great! But it's a little longer than needed, I reduced it down to `if (currentBuild.upstreamBuilds) { ... }`. If `upstreamBuilds` isn't present, or is present but is empty, Groovy considers it _falsey_. If it's present and contains at least 1 element, it's _truthy_.